# Having to call subscribe() on Retrofit observable twice when routed through BehaviorRelay

Tags: android, rx-java2

I create a `BehaviorRelay` then use `accept()` to begin a network call.

```
BehaviorRelay<Object> behaviorRelay = BehaviorRelay.createDefault(Observable.empty());
behaviorRelay.accept(searchDiscogsInteractor.getArtistsReleases(id));
```

This is what is done with the network call `Observable`:

```
public Single<List<Release>> getArtistsReleases(String artistId)
    {
        return discogsService.getArtistReleases(artistId, token, "asc", "500")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .flatMapIterable(RootReleaseResponse::getReleases)
                .filter(release -> !release.getRole().equals("TrackAppearance"))
                .toList();
    }
```

When I then `subscribe()` to that `BehaviorRelay` I need to subscribe to the subscription to get the correct result. In the first subscription I get back an `ObservableToListSingle` which I can then `subscribe()` to and then get the correct value.

```
behaviorRelay.subscribe(o ->
        {
            Log.e(TAG, o.toString());
            ((ObservableToListSingle) o).subscribe(o1 ->
                    Log.e(TAG, o1.toString())); <-- correct value
        });
```

Why is this happening? Am I missing a call to `subscribe()` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

What you expected to happen? Did you expect `BehaviorRelay` to emit `List<Release>`?

You declared `BehaviorRelay<Object>` which in fact is `BehaviorRelay<Observable>`, so you are emitting `Observable` and not `List<Release>`.

I think this is what you are for:

```
searchDiscogsInteractor.getArtistsReleases(id)
                       .subscribe(releaseList -> relay.accept(releaseList));
```

Now, when subscribed to `relay` you would get `List<Release>`.